# Best way to start/maintain activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, savestate, android-savedstate

I'm trying to redesign my android app, but I'm not sure what the best programming method is for what I'm trying to do.

Currently, I have a page in my navigation drawer called "My Workout". In this page I have an expandable list view, and each item is a workout and contains 4 child items (Week 1 to week 4). When they click on a child item, a new activity is opened with 3 fragment tabs (Mon, Wed, Fri). Each tab contains a recycler view that is populated depending on the exp list view item clicked.

Id like to change it so the expandable list view activity is called "Choose a Workout", and the expandable list view is turned into a normal listview. When an item is clicked it goes to a new page(My Workout) in the navigation drawer and starts a new.. "activity" in the app. So instead of having the user have to go to each item, then the week, then the day, it'll simply load the first day(with the recycler view) on a new page. There will then be a button on that page saying "Completed", and when clicked, it will bring up the next day (Week 1 Wed), and it will continue that until the month is complete.

I'm pretty sure I can get this to work with simple intents and intent extras. The problem I am worried about is how will the app react when it is closed and re-opened to My Workout from the navigation drawer? As far as I know the intent will be lost because it is no longer coming from the listview page (Choose a Workout).

Does anyone know what the best way to save what workout they are on in the "My Workout" page, so if they start a specific workout, then close the app, then re-open it and go directly to the "My Workout" page, it is the same place they left off?

Thanks!

Comment: Save the position or parent/child object references in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Sorry pretty new to android, but do you mean so when the user clicks an item in the listview, it adds a value to shared pref, then when they open the "My Workout" tab, it checks to see what value was passed before setting the layout? Then when the last item is completed, in the completed button I just delete the value or set it to a default value?

Comment: Basically, yes. You can either set the value each time they click something or just before exiting the list. Like in `onPause()` or whatever works best for your situation.

Comment: Okay thank you, didn't think of that, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Best possible ways are using `SharedPreference` or `SQLite`. Saving the result in `SharedPreference` is always preferred. Save result into preference, once the user comes back to the app, check the result of the previously saved data/stage(whatever according to your app) and perform the action.